# How to display only the number of lines that contain a string pattern in csv file using grep without showing the content of the line?

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am reviewing my bash knowledge and I stuck on the following:
I want to count the number of the last few lines that match the string 'Wed' which is case insensitive in one csv file. I do not need the content of the line though.

```
INPUT="$1"
IFS=","
last_rows=$(tail -n 10 $INPUT)
echo $(grep -c 'Wed' $last_rows)

output:
grep:  Wednesday: No such file or directory
```

but this gives me grep: (the content of the line): no such file or directory
Can anyone please give me any hints?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `grep` is expecting `stdin`

Comment: Do `$(tail -n 10 $INPUT | grep -c 'Wed')`.  Or `echo $(echo "$last_rows" | grep -c 'Wed')`

Comment: check from here, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/163810/grep-on-a-variable

Comment: @YangZiqi : `last_rows` contains the string _Wednesday_, and you ask grep to search the pattern in a file named 'Wednesday'. Also, I don't see any reason why you want to do a `echo` here, since `grep` writes to stdout anyway.

Answer (score 0):

To grep inside a string, you do a

```
grep -c Wed <<<$last_rows
```

Of course, if you don't need the content of `last_rows` in a different place of your script, there is no point in using a variable. Instead, you just do a

```
tail -n 10 "$INPUT" | grep -c Wed
```

Don't forget to quote `$INPUT`, otherwise the code will fail if the filename contains a space.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
tail -n 10 "$INPUT" | grep -i -c wed
```

The option `-i` makes the search in `grep` case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

An alternatie approach using GNU awk.

Print the file in reverse using tac and then using awk, first tell awk to ignore case when doing string comparisons by setting IGNORECASE=1. When the line number is less than or equal to 10 and the line contains case insensitive "Wed", increment a counter variable cnt. At the end, print cnt.

```
tac file | awk 'BEGIN { IGNORECASE=1 } NR <= 10 && /Wed/ { cnt+=1 } END { print cnt }'
```

Comment: Then in this case should NR be <=10? if I want the 10th row as well?

Comment: Yes, I've amended the answer